# Origin of quote “In order to simplify…”

Tags: complex-numbers, soft-question, math-history, meta-math

**I am looking for the origin of a quote found in a mathematics textbook and attributed to Mandelbrot.**

I'm convinced that a math book we used in high school had this quote in it:

> ***In order to simplify, one must complexify, i.e., see simple things in the complex plane.***

The book, which looked like it was printed in the '90s, attributed this quote to Benoît Mandelbrot.

However, the Internet does not seems to have any mentions of this quote, and in particular not by Mandelbrot.

Now I wonder… **has anyone heard of this quote or a variation of it?**
And could it have been said by Mandelbrot, perhaps in a talk or so?

My book was in Dutch but the quote itself was printed in English. The original quote might have been in a different language, perhaps French; however, I don't find any results either when looking for its translated keywords.

Comment: May be better asked at [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @BeKind Thank you; will try that!

Comment: There's a famous quote by Hadamard that might be what you were thinking of: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/61913/what-does-this-jacques-hadamard-quote-mean

Comment: books.google.com shows this phrase used on page 905 of "Deciphering the Chemical Code: Bonding Across the Periodic Table" by N. D. Epiotis, but it's part of the phrase `reconfirming the motto of the mathematician : " To simplify , one must complexify `. The book was published in 1996.

Comment: See also https://datamining.typepad.com/data_mining/2008/12/to-simplify-complexify.html

Comment: @barrycarter Interesting, Google Search currently shows as an only hit this very question. Had not considered separately checking Google Books. We're getting closer!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22simplify%22+%22complexify%22+%22complex%22+%22plane%22 suggests it might have been Mandelbrot: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Fractals_and_Chaos/q0AmBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22simplify%22+%22complexify%22+%22complex%22+%22plane%22&pg=PA73&printsec=frontcover

Comment: @GEdgar and barrycarter You are getting very close. Interesting because my keyword searches have been missing those for years.

Comment: Correction: Mandelbrot quotes this as "a favorite saying of Gaston Julia"

Comment: @barrycarter I think you've nailed it with Gaston Julia. He's quoted as "when one wishes to simplify a theory, one should complexify the variables" by Mandelbrot in "Fractals and Chaos: The Mandelbrot Set and Beyond". Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to deviate from my usual policy of never answering a question because I can't "really" post images in comments, and complex google searches may yield different results for different people.

The answer: Gaston Julia

The link: https://www.google.com/search?q=gaston+julia+%22complexify%22+simplify&newwindow=1&tbm=bks&ei=IILVYtXxBYyG0PEPpty-uAw&ved=0ahUKEwjVgbmG5oL5AhUMAzQIHSauD8cQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=gaston+julia+%22complexify%22+simplify&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQ2AdY9xZgmhpoAHAAeACAAVyIAfgBkgEBM5gBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books

The screenshot:

[image]

As https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&hl=en&q=inauthor:%22Gaston+Julia%22&tbm=bks notes, Julia wrote almost entirely in French, so the expression was most likely translated to English. To find an original source, you might have to change the search terms.